# Pass variable from Javascript to Servlet Method get Return value

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

Can i be provided with an example of a scenario whereby i have a Servet as such :

```
@WebServlet(name = "testservlet", urlPatterns = {"/testservlet"})
public class testservlet extends HttpServlet {    

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

          Data d = new Data();  
          ArrayList infos = d.getData(String ID);  

        }
```

How can i pass the value for getData method in javascript using ajax and receive the reply by sending back the infos object ? I will appreciate an example in javascript. This should be triggered by an on button click. Please your reply should be like a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user enters value to web page, you have to use `ajax` to transfer that value to java servlet. This is not the exact code but an example,You can have the servlet retrieve data from postVariableName.

Lets say you have a id=1 in javascript file,

```
var id= document.getElementById(id);
```

then use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/testservlet',
    data: {
        postVariableName: id
    },
    type: 'POST'
});​
```

In servlet, you will access the value by:

```
id = request.getParameter("id")
System.out.print("id is:"+id); //prints 1
```

See also:

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea where the return value is stored ? it's in json format. I will like to iterate though the return value. How may i store the return values ? is it in the ajax{ ?

Comment: return value for what?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my mind:

1. Convert values from getData method to JSON
2. Put the JSON value in a HTML hidden element.
3. Use javascript to fetch hidden element's value and send via Ajax.